# JQuery Ajax function now working

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have wrote an ajax function and it partially works. Doesn't give any errors . but when i add alert to check my values it works completely . It renders the complete thing . Can any one tell me where did i do wrong in here

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/usermanageajax/",
        data : 'key=' + key_value,
        success : function (data) {
                var element = users.salary[users.salary.length -1];
                var hrs = users.hours[users.hours.length -1];
                var html = "<span title=\"" + users.name + "\">Name \"" + users.desc(0,50) + "...\" "+ "has  " + element + "  of "+ hrs + "</span>";
                // alert('*');
                $('#title').html(html);
                chart_s = draw_chart(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
});
```

Comment: You said it works, so what's the question/problem?

Comment: well it wont show elements and hrs if we exclude the alert . it shows the complete html string if we include the alert

Comment: Where is it called from? Is it in a document.ready handler and/or _after_ the #title element in the page source? Where is `draw_chart()` defined?

Comment: What do you mean by " Doesn't give any errors" and "it works completely", is it working or not. What you want to ask?

Comment: from the Document.Ready nothing wrong with other things

Comment: and i cannot give you the entire source, i have only place where i have the problem

Answer (score 0):

The justification of this issue is that the alert call blocks the calling of the two next line. Seems that the browser needs some milliseconds to achieve something before performing the two next lines.

Try to call setTimeOut on the two other lines to be called after few milliseconds.
Again, what is the browser you are testing on?

Comment: firefox 3.6.3 Ubuntu version works on a one Ubuntu PC and does not work on other though have the same firefox version

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works with the alert indicates a race condition.

Try moving your code to a complete handler instead of a success handler.  You can also check for success there.